# How does Google Play Store App request permission before downloading the app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have got an app that fetches the list of several apps from my own server. By clicking download button in the list row, user can download an apk for the app and install it.

As you know when you install app with apk it requests permission before you install it. However, Google Play Store App requests permission before you download the app and don't ask you for permission before installing.

Can I get the same functionality for my app? Meaning, **request permission before user download** the app and **don't ask for permission before they install** the app?

Comment: If your query is resolved, you may accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Store reads details from the APK when the developer uploads it on their developer console and it is stored on their server separately. These details include a lot of information like required permissions, hardware features, platform support, screen size and other properties specified in the APK. Using these details they filter the visibility of the apps for different audiences.

Before the APK is downloaded, they fetch the list of permission from the server and present it to the user. You can definitely do this in your application, but it does not really have much that you can do on the client side except for fetching and displaying the list.

**EDIT:**

You might want to look at this gist about installing applications with `INSTALL_PACKAGE` permission: https://gist.github.com/Fuzion24/2623253

You will need to invoke `PackageManager.installPackage()` through reflection. This method needs a system permission - `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` which your application will get only if it is in the `/system` partition and not `/data` partition (where all the user apps are).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I didn't ask about how to just show the list of permissions app requests before downloading it. I want to tell the Operating System NOT TO ask for permissions before installing the apk as long as user grants permissions before downloading the app.

Comment: Do you have root access or system permissions on the system?

Comment: Users may not have root access. But, Google Play Store App does that on any phones regardless of root access. If they can do it, then there must be some workaround.

Comment: As I asked about **system permissions**, Google Play Store has access to it, hence it can. You will need either of the two to do it. Check my edited answer for a way to install APKs without user action with system permissions.

Comment: Does snippet you gave require root access?

Comment: what is actually system permissions and how can I get it?

Comment: The snippet I shared does not require root, but it requires a system permission `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` which you'll be able to get only if your application is within the `/system` partition of the device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131773/discussion-between-kamran-ahmed-and-umarov).